# Xamarin Android Cant pass string to toolbar.setTitle

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

using xamarin Android in visual studio c#.
I am trying to set the title for my toolbar but am getting the error

> "Cannot convert from string to int".

How do I set my title so that I can pass it to the `SetTitle` method?

```
    var toolbar = FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

    toolbar.SetTitle("This is the title");

    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: `toolbar.Title = "This is the title";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'Title' property instead of the 'SetTitle' method. The method is probably expecting a Resource Id. I would recommend setting it after calling `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. For some reason, the order of operations with the Support Action Bar matters in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

It expects a string resource ID - not a string as argument.
Here's the declaration of that method.

```
public virtual void SetTitle(int resId);
```

You need to create a string value and pass its id there.

If you need to set the value as a direct string (ensure localization correctness) then you can use the Title property.